# Protecting encryption key with TPM when using DPAPI

Tags: windows, security, encryption-symmetric, tpm, dpapi

DPAPI on Windows provides functions to encrypt and decrypt arbitrary data. Functions provided by DPAPI include `CryptProtectMemory`, `CryptUnprotectMemory`, `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData`. I suspect that functions `RtlEncryptMemory` and `RtlDecryptMemory` from ntsecapi.h also use DPAPI, altough it's not stated in documentation.

In the past, security of the encryption key was apparently based on user's credentials [1]. **If a TPM is available, will DPAPI use** it to protect its encryption key instead? If so, for which of the functions previously listed is this true?

In the event that an attacker can dump the entire RAM (e.g. through DMA), will the sensitive data encrypted with DPAPI be protected? Assume that the attacker cannot access the TPM in this scenario.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)

I tried to search through available Microsoft documentation for all the functions listed, documentation for DPAPI and documentation for how Windows uses TPM (CNG etc.). I also explored papers reversing DPAPI like this one: https://elie.net/static/files/recovering-windows-secrets-and-efs-certificates-offline/recovering-windows-secrets-and-efs-certificates-offline-paper.pdf

Unfortunately, the information is either outdated or too general to be useful.

Comment: DPAPI algorithms and CSP are configurable https://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=28#14. By default it will use MS_STRONG_PROV but you can force it to use another CSP if you specify algorithms MS_STRONG_PROV doesn't know. But this is only for encryption and MAC computation, it will not change the way it fundamentally works. It won't store data elsewhere but on disk.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier! So if I understand this correctly, I might succeed in forcing it to change the algorithm it's using, but the keys will always be stored in RAM/HDD, as described in the [paper](https://elie.net/static/files/recovering-windows-secrets-and-efs-certificates-offline/recovering-windows-secrets-and-efs-certificates-offline-paper.pdf)?

Comment: Not only the keys, but the full data (blobs, etc.) As for CryptProtectMemory, it's quite different, it does not store the blobs.

Comment: Go it. Do you know if the same is true for [CNG DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-dpapi)?

Comment: I don't know but when you read it, it's been designed for "content encrypted on one computer to be decrypted on another". It's possible it uses TPM to generate MAC/random/keys, etc. but I don't think anything can be stored in it.

Answer (score -2):

CNG DPAPI consists of two functions, `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData`. The Trusted Platform Module (TPM) technology is designed to provide hardware-based, security-related functions, primarily involving encryption keys.

In contrast to software-only CNG providers, TPM features provide key protection. The Platform Crypto Provider can create keys in the TPM with restrictions on their use. As far as I'm concerned,to protect key, you could try to create keys in the TPM instead of storing the key in the TPM.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Docs:

[TPM fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/tpm-fundamentals)

[How Windows uses the Trusted Platform Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/how-windows-uses-the-tpm)

Comment: _"CNG DPAPI consists of two functions, `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData`"_ - this is false. Look at [CNG DPAPI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-dpapi), `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData` are the old DPAPI functions. CNG DPAPI functions are starting with `NCrypt*`

Comment: `DPAPI` is part of `CryptoAPI`. `DPAPI-NG` is built on top of `Cryptography Next Generation (CNG)`. `CNG` is the long-term replacement for the `CryptoAPI`.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I am wondering if you understand what OP is asking about. You seem just copy-pasting. Moreover, you change your copypasta and make invalid calims ("_CNG DPAPI consists of two functions, CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData_").

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT To top it all, Platform Crypto Provider won't "_create keys in the TPM_" as you claim. Keys are created and kept on disk. TPM can be used to protect (encrypt) them.